# Center an image that is too big

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment

I have an image, and in order for it to look good i need to make the width bigger that the part of the page where I am suppose to add text, so it gets shifted to the right. Is there a way to center it, even if it is too big (I am fine with it going beyond the margin, but I want to do so equally on both sides). Thank you!

This is my code

```
\begin{figure}[htbp] 
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=18cm, height=6cm]{Figure.png} 
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:outflow}
 \end{figure}
```